# How do I write an integration test for a REST API secured with OAuth2 in JUnit5?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing

I have a client service like this,

```
@Service
public class PersonClientService {
  private final String EXTERNAL_API;
  private RestTemplate restTemplate;

  @Autowired
  public PersonClientService(RestTemplate restTemplate, @Value("${person.url}") String apiUrl) {
    this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    EXTERNAL_API = apiUrl
  }

  public ResponseDTO createData(PersonDTO personDTO) throws Exception {
    try {
      HttpEntity<PersonDTO> input = new HttpEntity<>(personDTO);
      ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO> restponseDTO = restTemplate.exchange(EXTERNAL_API, HttpMethod.POST, input, ResponseDTO.class);
      return responseDTO.getBody();
    } catch(Exception e) {
      //catch exception
    }
  }
}
```

Now the rest template here that I am using is secured with OAuth2 implementation and it is using `client_id` and `secret` with `grant_type` as `client_credentials` to generate a token and then using this token as header to call the `EXTERNAL_API`

I am following this guide here but it's not really helpful since it is using JUnit4 and I am on JUnit5: https://www.baeldung.com/oauth-api-testing-with-spring-mvc

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused. What do you want to test?

The sample you link is achieving controller unit-testing with mockmvc.

They use an annotation which loads security context. As a consequence test security context must be configured for the request to reach controller endpoint.

I don't see any security rules on your service (@PreAuthorize or something) => you don't need any security context, just don't load security config.

If you add security rules you want to unit test, load security config and setup test security context (either explicitly or with something like https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/webmvc-jwtauthenticationtoken/src/test/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/samples/webmvc_jwtauthenticationtoken)

The call to external service is a complete different story: the external service is running with a different security context than the one attached to your tested service thread). Either:

- `@MockBean RestTemplate` (and configure mock for the Rest call your service is issuing) => unit test
- ensure test configuration for RestTemplate and external service points to the same started authorization server, load rest template config, auto wire RestTemplate as normal and let it issue request for real to actual external service (which must be started too) => integration test.

You should not start with integration test. Unit test are for more stable and easier to maintain.